# Execute Javascript Fetch() Request After PHP Code Executes Successfully

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I have a form for resetting a user email which currently consists of a password input element, and a 'Change email address' email input.

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="form-row-password" class="form-row">
        <label for="password">Enter Password</label>
        <input class="input-gateway" type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>
    <div id="form-row-email" class="form-row">
        <label for="email">Change Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row form-row-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="update-email" id="button" value="SEND ACTIVATION LINK">
    </div>
</form>
```

With this current form you enter your password and the email address, and then you get emailed a link to confirm your new/change of email address and it all works as desired.

The current PHP process is as follows:

1. Santisation and validations of inputs
2. PDO Prepared Statments that update the mysql database

**What I Wish To Achieve**

What I want to do is have it so this process is split over two stages using AJAX/fetch() in javascript.

The first step would be the user entering their password, and when verified with the database this input disappears and is replaced with the 'new email address' input element.

I've set up some test javascript that fetches this second input element using a 'test' button.

What I want to do is have this fetch() javascript code trigger when then first stage is successful in the PHP code. But I cannot work out how to do this?

The PHP that processes the inputs I will included in the HTML partials that get added and removed by the fetch() javascript so I'm not concerned about that side of things.

Will I use a 'submit' event listener or an 'onchange' event listener and how will the javascript know that the password submission has been successful when this is done in PHP?

```
// PSEUDO JAVASCRIPT

let button = document.getElementById('button'),
    formRowPassword = document.getElementById('form-row-password'),
    formRowEmail = document.getElementById('form-row-email');

var filePath = "modals/email-reset-modal.php";

// what type of event listener is best to use ??

button.addEventListener('click', function(){

    fetch(filePath)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then((data)=>{
            formRowPassword = '';
            formRowEmail.textContent = data;
        })
        .catch((error => {console.log(error)}))
})
```

Is there a built-in PHP function that can effectively talk to javascript so it executes once the password input (1st stage) has been successful?

Any help would be amazing.

Anna

Comment: ```how will the javascript know that the password submission has been successful when this is done in PHP?``` : you can read the response body of your ajax/fetch call

Comment: @Kristian I don't understand how to do that though? I'm new to both PHP and Javascript and this is where I have hit the wall. Could you give a simple pseudo code example?

Comment: oversimplified example of php file that handle the ajax: ```if($loginSuccess) echo "1"; else echo "0";```